# Ошибка при запуске проекта ASP. NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

При запуске проекта появляется окно со следующей ошибкой:

> ошибка при попытке определить идентификатор процесса dotnet.exe

запускаю на IIS в 17 студии.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1719

I've had the same issue, and it turned out that I simply didn't have the right version of the runtime (1.1.0); instead I was trying to use 1.1.0 assemblies with 1.0.1 runtime.

The resolution is simple - download and install SDK from here, but pick the right version! It turned out that if you want version 1.1.0 you should select "Current" option (button).

Basically the problem is caused by stupid interface at the referenced page - if you don't pay attention you'll download v1.0.1 since it is "LTS" version, and "LTS" option is default there. What to say... Yet another disappointment from .NET team in this crazy-versioning, crazy-moniker, crazy-platform times

Answer (score 1):

Возникала ошибка "Произошла ошибка при попытке определить идентификатор процесса dotnet.exe...". Мне помогло следующее:

1. Закрыть VisualStudio.
2. В папке решения удалить скрытую папку ".vs".
3. Заново открыть решение.

Comment: И за что минус спрашивается?! Во-первых мне это реально помогло, а информации для дальнейшего "копания" решения в вопросе не абы как много. Или на английском отвечать нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте csproj файл и посмотрите секцию TargetFramework, и попробуйте установить значение netcoreapp2.0.